# conflict between fortran+iso_c_binding (via ctypes or cython) and matplotlib when reading namelist [only with python Anaconda!!]

Tags: matplotlib, fortran, ctypes, cython, anaconda

**[EDIT: the problem only applies with python anaconda, not with standard /usr/bin/python2.7]**

**[FYI: [the gist referred to in this post](https://gist.github.com/perrette/7da3b5ac72fa846dad6d) can still be useful for anyone trying to use fortran with ctypes or cython, credit to http://www.fortran90.org/src/best-practices.html]**

When using a fortran code from within python (using iso_c_bindings), either via ctypes or via cython, I ran into a weird incompatibility problem with matplotlib. Basically, if matplotlib is "activated" (via %pylab or by using pyplot.plot command), reading the namelist will omit any digit !! i.e. The value 9.81 is read as 9.00. Without matplotlib, no problem.

I made [a minimal working example gist.github.com](https://gist.github.com/perrette/7da3b5ac72fa846dad6d).

Basically, the fortran module just allow reading a double precision parameter g from a namelist, and store it as global module variable. It can also print its value to string, and allow directly setting its value from the outside. This makes three functions:

- read_par
- print_par
- set_par

You can download the gist example and then run:

```
make ctypes
python test_ctypes.py
```

test_ctypes.py contains:

```
from ctypes import CDLL, c_double
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f = CDLL('./lib.so')

print "Read param and print to screen"
f.read_par()
f.print_par()

# calling matplotlib's plot command seem to prevent
# subsequent namelist reading
print "Call matplotlib.pyplot's plot"
plt.plot([1,2],[3,4])

print "Print param just to be sure: everything is fine"
f.print_par()

print "But any new read will lose decimals on the way!"
f.read_par()
f.print_par()

print "Directly set parameter works fine"
f.set_par(c_double(9.81))
f.print_par()

print "But reading from namelist really does not work anymore"
f.read_par()
f.print_par()
```

With the output:

```
Read param and print to screen
g   9.8100000000000005     
Call matplotlib.pyplot's plot
Print param just to be sure: everything is fine
g   9.8100000000000005     
But any new read will lose decimals on the way!
g   9.0000000000000000     
Directly set parameter works fine
g   9.8100000000000005     
But reading from namelist really does not work anymore
g   9.0000000000000000
```

The same happen with the cython example (make clean; make cython; python test_cython.py).

Does anyone know what is going on, or whether there is any workaround?? The main reason why I wrote a wrapper to my fortran code is to be able to play around with a model, set parameters (via namelist), run it, plot the result, set other parameters and so on. So for my use case this bug kinds of defies the purpose of interactivity...

Many thanks for any hint.

PS: I am happy to file a bug somewhere, but would not know where (gfortran? matplotlib?)

Comment: Here are my specs: 

- OS: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS  64bit
- Python 2.7.8 :: Anaconda 1.9.1 (64-bit)
- matplotlib v1.3.1
- compiler: gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem in Ubuntu 14.04 using the system 64-bit Python 2.7.6 and packages from the main repo (not Anaconda).

Comment: Are you sure the unit 8 is free for use?

Comment: @VladimirF : the problem persists with unit 8236 ...

Comment: @eryksun I installed matplotlib outside anaconda, the bug is gone...All right, thanks for your suggestion. That and the annoying Ctrl+C not working in Anaconda's ipython is a bit disappointing...